# Livewire validateOnly with validate in the same component

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have a little problem with the data validation with **livewire** ( laravel ).

I noticed that when I set up the validation in real time ( **validateOnly()** ), the information entered in the form is validated in real time. At this level everything is fine.

But when I click on the button to submit the form (even though the form contains errors), the form is unfortunately sent to my function defined in the **wire:submit**.

So my question is : is it possible to revalidate the information in the **wire:submit** method that receives the data after the form is submitted ? If so, how can I do that?

PS: I tried to set the validate method in my wire:submit function but nothing happens. It blocks the form from being submitted but it doesn't give me an error .

My source code :

```
<?php
class UserProfile extends Component
{
    use WithFileUploads;

    public $countries = [];
    public $profile = [];

    protected function rules() {
        if ( !LivewireUpdateProfileRequest::authorize() ) {
            return abort(403, "Your are not authorized to make this request !");
        }
        $rules = LivewireUpdateProfileRequest::rules();

        if ( !empty($this->profile['phone']) ) {
            $rules['profile.phone'] = [ 'required', 'phone_number:' . $this->profile['phone'] ];
        }

        return $rules;
    }


    public function mount()
    {
        $this->countries = Countries::all();
        $this->profile = Auth::user()->toArray();
    }


    public function updateUserProfile()
    {
        $validatedData = $this->validate();
        dd( $validatedData );
    }

    public function updated($key, $value)
    {
        $this->validateOnly($key);
    }


    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.user-profile');
    }
}
```

Html source :

```
 <form action="" method="POST" wire:submit.prevent="updateUserProfile">
    <input name="profile.email" type="email" wire:model="profile.email" />
    @error('profile.email') {{ $message }} @enderror

    <input name="profile.phone" type="tel" wire:model="profile.phone" />
    @error('profile.phone') {{ $message }} @enderror
</form>
```

Here is LivewireUpdateProfileRequest content :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests\Web;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class LivewireUpdateProfileRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public static function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public static function rules()
    {
        return [
            'profile' => ['required', 'array', 'size:10'],
            'profile.firstname' => ['required', 'string'],
            'profile.lastname' => ['required', 'string'],
            'profile.email' => ['required', 'email'],
            'profile.phone' => ['required', 'phone_number:33'],
            'profile.gender' => ['required', 'gender'],
            'profile.image' => ['sometimes', 'image', 'mimes:png,jpg,jpeg'],
            'profile.address' => ['required', 'string'],
            'profile.city' => ['required', 'string'],
            'profile.country_id' => ['required', 'exists:countries,id'],
            'profile.birth_at' => ['required', 'date', 'min_age:18'],
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually in your saving method you would run validation once more for all fields. The livewire docs share this example:

Livewire Component:

```
class ContactForm extends Component
{
    public $name;
    public $email;

    protected $rules = [
        'name' => 'required|min:6',
        'email' => 'required|email',
    ];

    public function updated($propertyName)
    {
        $this->validateOnly($propertyName);
    }

    public function saveContact()
    {
        $validatedData = $this->validate();

        Contact::create($validatedData);
    }
}
```

With this HTML:

```
<form wire:submit.prevent="saveContact">
    <input type="text" wire:model="name">
    @error('name') <span class="error">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror

    <input type="text" wire:model="email">
    @error('email') <span class="error">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror

    <button type="submit">Save Contact</button>
</form>
```

This should validate the inputs near-realtime using the `updated`-method and on submit using the `saveContact`-method.

If you could share your code, we could debug it easier.

Source: https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/input-validation#real-time-validation

Comment: I tried to set the validate method in my wire:submit function but nothing happens. It blocks the form from being submitted but it doesn't give me an error .

I have just added the source code. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I've had a quick look and was wondering where `LivewireUpdateProfileRequest` comes from. That's unclear to me atm. What speaks against moving the validation rules into the method directly?

Comment: I just added the contents of the `LivewireUpdateProfileRequest` file to my question. Please have a look at it. It's just a simple class that I use to feed the validation rules.

Comment: Looks plausible on the first impression. Can you dumb the data+rules before the validation to see if everything is set as to expect?

Comment: Yes I did, but it didn't work. The problem is with the validation function in the wire:submit. the real time validation works fine but when we submit the form because of the call to the `$this->validate();` function I get nothing. which means that this `$this->validate();` function reports that the data entered is not valid (while the real time validation says the opposite)

Comment: Can you share the outputs just before the call of `$this->validate();`? Just to see if anything stands out.

Comment: The `$this->validate();` function block data from being passed to the dd() method; basically it blocks the form submission...

Comment: Yes, that's happening when the validation fails (expected behavior). That's why dumping it before is important.

Comment: How can I do that ? because I also use these functions `$this->resetErrorBag();` and after `$this->resetValidation();` before using : `$validatedData = $this->validate();`

But that didn't help me much.

Comment: Just put it in the line before the call.

Comment: `public function updateUserProfile()
 {
  $this->resetValidation();
  $validatedData = $this->validate();
  dd( $validatedData );
 }`
It doesn't work ... the dd(); function is not reached.

Comment: I don't aim for the `$validatedData`, just the values and rules: `public function updateUserProfile() {
        dd([
            $this->profile,
            $this->rules(),
        ]);
        $validatedData = $this->validate();
}`

Comment: The error came from the fact that I had set a size for the array $this->profile. and that some fields were optional. problem solved.

Comment: Ah awesome, great that you managed to fix it!